# How to store a list of objects' parameters when each object has a bit different set of parameters?

Tags: mysql, nosql

I have a list of objects, each object can have a different set of parameters.
for example:

obg1: param1: value,  param2: value , param3: value
obg2: param1: value , param2: value , param4: value
obg3: param5: value , param6: value , param7: value

Each object has about 100 parameters, and the total number of distinct parameters is about 2000, and more can be added in the future.

I'm looking for an implementation that is suitable for finding clusters (objects with an identical set of parameters ) and retrieving all the data of an object.

Currently, the data is saved in the SQL DB with the following structure:

| obgID | param | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| obg 1 | param1 | value1 |
| obg 1 | param2 | value2 |
| obg 2 | param1 | value1 |
| obg 3 | param4 | value4 |

Comment: What have you tried so far and from your current example, what would be your desired result?

Comment: *I'm looking for an implementation that is suitable for finding clusters (objects with an identical set of parameters ) and retrieving all the data of an object.* Do you need in complete indentity? If so, and if this task is performed often, then I'd think about bit-mapped VARBINARY column which contains existing parameters map. This 'd allow to find these complete dulplicates (more precisely - their map value) with simple GROUP BY.